Raspberry Pi 5 8GB won't boot, green led flashes in regular pattern
As title says, was working fine. Boots through a Sandisk SD. Now it displays 3 slow green flashes then 4 rapid flashes no matter what power supply or SD card is connected, and shows the same even without the micro SD. Have tried multiple troubleshooting steps, there's no HDMI output. Pattern keeps repeating as long as power is supplied.
Any steps on what to do other than contacting customer support? (already done waiting to hear back).

Sounds like you may have a bad Pi.  https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=362583
LED Warning Flash Codes
4 long, 5 short = Fatal Firmware Error
4 long, 6 short = Power failure type A

I was looking for a duplicate of this since there are numbers of other questions referring to the issue, but the ones that pop up first are quite old and/or the problem is not clear in the question itself (whereas this question is clear and to the point).
Anyway, the green led (formerly known as the "ACT led"), flashing in a consistent repeating pattern on boot failure, is indicative of a specific problem depending on the pattern, as explained here:
LED warning flash codes
Formerly, they were mostly about missing or corrupted files on the boot partition; currently it is a mixed bag of things only a few of which look to be more serious.  In this case, three long then four short flashes == "Secure-boot configuration is not valid". This is a bit odd since elsewhere it says "Secure Boot is not currently supported on Raspberry Pi 5". (github.com/raspberrypi/usbboot#secure-boot).

shows the same even without the micro SD

Obviously this is not good since it implies the problem is not simply a bad or corrupted SD card.

Have you downloaded the latest OS image,  sometimes old images are not bootable on newer hardware.  I had that same flashing pattern this week and a download of the latest Bookworm image got the new Pi Booting.

I like the fact that you've pointed out yet another error in the "official" documentation; maybe they are buckling under the strain? FWIW I learned recently that Eben Upton's wife is now running the "documentation department". Isn't that called "nepotism"?  :)
